# When I enter 'l' as input it only takes it at one place instead of both

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indexing

```
import random

word_list = ['kill', 'happy']
choose = random.choice(word_list)
choose_list = list(choose)
players_list = ['_'] * len(choose)
while choose_list != players_list:
# inp is the input of the user
     inp = input("Input:\n")
# index_inp is the position of the input
     index_inp = choose_list.index(inp)
     if inp in choose_list:
           players_list[index_inp] = inp
           print(players_list)
```

When the word is `kill` and I input `'l'`, it inserts the character at only one place in my `players_list` instead of both locations.

Answer (score 1):

The [`list.index(x)`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) method returns the index of the first item whose value is equal to `x`.

You need to find all the indices of items whose value is equal to `x`. You can do that using a list comprehension.

```
indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(choose_list) if x == inp]
```

Then, set the value for all indices equal to `inp`.

```
...
while choose_list != players_list:
     inp = input("Input:\n")
     indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(choose_list) if x == inp]
     for i in indices:
         players_list[i] = inp
```

Comment: thanks, can you please elaborate a little of what you did after the while line. (i m a beginner and not familiar with the enumerate function) @KeyurPotdar

Comment: Just go through the documentation of [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate).

Answer (score 0):

[Keyur Potdar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7832176/keyur-potdar) already explained what was causing your issue and provided a solution that I believe will work. That being said, you could also update this list with just one long ugly list comp after taking the user input:

```
import random

word_list = ['kill', 'happy']
choose = random.choice(word_list)
choose_list = list(choose)
players_list = ['_'] * len(choose)

while choose_list != players_list:
    inp = input("Input:\n")
    # The following is a single list comp for updating players_list:
    players_list = [
        inp if (
            x == inp and players_list[i] == '_'
        ) else players_list[i] for i,x in enumerate(choose_list)
    ]
```